# Change environment when using Pow server in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently using [Pow](http://pow.cx/) as a server in my Rails app, and need to change environments from development to production. I've added `RAILS_ENV = 'production'` to my config/environment file and restarted the server; however, logs are still being generated in `log/development`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yyou can find the answer from [Pow's FAQ](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/FAQ):

> **Can I run my app in different rails environments through Pow?**
>
> Pow is intended for development use only, but if you just want to test how your app behaves with the settings for your different environments (e.g. production), you can run the following from your app directory.
>
> `echo export RAILS_ENV=production > .powenv && touch tmp/restart.txt`

You can get more info about .powenv from [Pow's user manual](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.2).